# Cucumber with @IntegrationTest

Tags: cucumber, spring-boot

I want to run cucumber for my test, but without run first my api rest, for this reason I include @IntegrationTest in my RunCakes. class, but when I run my integration test, the application don't start.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(format = { "pretty", "html:target/cucumber-html-  report" }, dryRun = false, strict = true, features = { "classpath:features" })
@IntegrationTest({ "server.port=9001", "spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:./target/repos/configuration-sample", 
"spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap=false", "ldap.uri=" , "security.ignored="})
public class RunCukesIT {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely looking for `@WebIntegrationTest` instead of `@IntegrationTest`.

Comment: and how can I run my api?. I run cucumber, but my application (spring boot) doesn't run.

Comment: I'm not familiar with cucumber, just noticed you're using the wrong annotation. Was worth a shot. Did you have a look at this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20717677/any-got-spring-boot-working-with-cucumber-jvm