# Cucumber with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cucumber, spring-boot-test

I know that there is some similar issue, but I have some problem with bind steps to feature cucumber file. This is my **cucumber runner**

```
  @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
  public class CucumberTests {

  }
```

**annotation**

```
 @Target(ElementType.TYPE)
 @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
 @SpringBootTest(classes = AppRunner.class)
 @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
 @interface CucumberSteps {

 }
```

**steps**

```
    @CucumberSteps
    public class QueueSenderStepsDefs {

        @Given("^I have item$")
        public void iHaveItem() throws Throwable {
            System.out.println("Asd");
        }

        @When("^I send it to jmsQueueSender$")
        public void iSendItToJmsQueueSender() throws Throwable {
            System.out.println("dff");
        }

        @Then("^item is on queue$")


   public void itemIsOnQueue() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("sdasdsa");
    }
}
```

I always get "You can implement missing steps with the snippets below: ". I use InteliJ IDEA and I have set glue in configuration. But still doesn't works. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Can you also copy in your feature?
And try using glue/feature in your cucumber options just to make sure it's looking in the right place for your files.
Similar to the below.

```
@CucumberOptions(
features ="src/test/java/",
glue = "packagename")
```

I also located a question that may assist you as it seems similar in nature [Cucumber Test a Spring Boot Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30667729/cucumber-test-a-spring-boot-application)